# How can I control PHP session expiry based on user selection?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I've got a basic PHP CRUD (PDO) framework with a login form which logs the user in and sets the default cookie PHPSESSID which expires when the session expires...

I'm happy with this basic set up but I would like to expand this by adding a 'Keep me logged in' option on the login form.

How do I go about this? Do I configure the expiry date of PHPSESSID and if so how/where do I do that, or do I create a new cookie different to PHPSESSID?

For reference, here's my user class:

```
include('password.php');
class User extends Password{

private $_db;

function __construct($db){
    parent::__construct();

    $this->_db = $db;
}

private function get_user_hash($username){

    try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, username, userID FROM users WHERE username = :username ');
        $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

        return $stmt->fetch();

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function login($username,$password){

    $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);

    if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password']) == 1){

        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['userID'] = $row['userID'];
        return true;
    }
}

public function logout(){
    session_destroy();
}

public function is_logged_in(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

Is it as simple as this?

```
if($keepmeloggedin == TRUE){

ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 2592000);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 2592000);

}

else{

ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 3600);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);

}
```